# What is single dot and two dot in filename during import in react?

Tags: reactjs

I am using react and I have imports with code as follows:
import Logo from './filename';
import Logo1 from '../filename';

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/63081/what-are-and-directories

Answer (score 1, accepted):

./ means "starting from the current directory". `.` refers to the current working directory, so something like `./foo.bar` would be looking for a file called `foo.bar` in the current directory. and, `..` refers to the parent directory of the current directory. So `../foo.bar` would be looking for that file one directory above the current directory.

Answer (score 0):

If your logo is in public folder then no need to put . or .. , just import '/logo.jpg'.